# How to show a random picture in a web page?

Tags: php, html

My website has an image in a certain place and when a user reloads the page he should see a different image on the same place. I have 30 images and I want to change them randomly on every reload. How do I do that?

Comment: how do you store the image path? database or from the file system?

Comment: in which language do you have those images; in js/php array, retrieve from database? also, [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: not from db. i just insert the pictures manually onto the page but when a user visit my site he see only one picture instead of all pictures.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".random-staff ul li").hide();

    var elements = $(".random-staff ul li");
    var elementCount = elements.size();
    var elementsToShow = 1;
    var alreadyChoosen = ",";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < elementsToShow) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
        if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
            alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
            elements.eq(rand).show();
            ++i;
        }
    }
});

Answer (score 8):

Make an array with the "picture information" (filename or path) you have, like

```
$pictures = array("pony.jpg", "cat.png", "dog.gif");
```

and randomly call an element of that array via

```
echo '<img src="'.$pictures[array_rand($pictures)].'" />';
```

Looks weird, but works.

Comment: where i should make the array? in db?

Comment: Before you guys ask: ;) => array_rand() gives back the INDEX KEY of an array, not the element itself ! see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: @UmairJaved: If the data is stored in a database, you would fetch it from the database into a PHP array.  Then you can just randomly select from that array as in this answer.  We don't know where/how your data is stored, though, so that's up to you.

Comment: @UmairJaved to make this thing very simple and constructive: simply put the paths of your images directly into the php code, like in the above example. setting up a database etc might be a little bit too much for this situation. not sexy, but it will show you the way how to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

The actual act of selecting a random image is going to require a random number.  There are a couple of methods that can help with this:

- [`rand()` is used to generate a random number](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).
- [`array_rand()` is used to select a random element's index from an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

You can think of the second function as a shortcut for using the first if you're specifically dealing with an array.  So, for example, if you have an array of image paths from which to select the one you want to display, you can select a random one like this:

```
$randomImagePath = $imagePaths[array_rand($imagePaths)];
```

If you're storing/retrieving the images in some other way, which you didn't specify, then you may not be able to use `array_rand()` as easily.  But, ultimately, you need to generate a random number.  So some use of `rand()` would work for this.

Comment: array_rand() just gives back the key/index, not the element itself. Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think oyur answer wouldnt work

Comment: @Panique: I think you may be right.  Answer has been updated.  Thanks!

Comment: it worksss thankyou so much....
but how i can give another image path???
i am giving like this  $images = glob("images/fb.png",GLOB_BRACE);
  $images = glob("images/ld.png",GLOB_BRACE);

Comment: @UmairJaved: What do you mean by "give another image path"?  Do you mean just manually adding more image paths to the array returned by `glob`?  You can add elements to an array, merge arrays together, etc.  PHP has a lot of information about array manipulation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @david can you please give mein full code that how could i do this?? i am not clear that where i should store arayy??? i have given the path live lawrene said to me $images = glob("./images/*.{png,jpg}",GLOB_BRACE);like this.. now how i give the path of images???

Comment: @UmairJaved: I can't "give full code" because I don't have any knowledge of your existing code. And I recommend against simply copying/pasting code you find online and expecting it to work in your code without any understanding of what that code actually does. (For example, in a now-deleted answer to this question, you pasted in code which was accessing your file system, then you didn't understand why it was failing... Did you even _notice_ that you were executing code that was accessing a file?) You can edit your question to include code and I can help with that, but I can't do it for you.

Comment: i dont want to take images from database.. i have stored 30 pictures in an image folder i want to take and show them randomly from images folder...

Comment: @UmairJaved: You can use something like `scandir()` to get an array of files within a folder: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php  Then you can randomly select from that array to include one in the response to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the information in your database, you can also SELECT a random image:

MySQL:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

PgSQL:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

Best,
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to create random images on popup is this method below.

(Note: You have to rename the images to "1.png", "2.png", etc.)

```
<?php
//This generates a random number between 1 & 30 (30 is the
//amount of images you have)
$random = rand(1,30);

//Generate image tag (feel free to change src path)
$image = <<<HERE
<img src="{$random}.png" alt="{$random}" />
HERE;
?>

* Content Here *

<!-- Print image tag -->
<?php print $image; ?>
```

This method is simple and I use this every time when I need a random image.

Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: This piece of code should work. Make sure you have **renamed** the images like "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", etc.

Comment: ok i have folder named as images... make a code for this like how could i fetch from there??

Comment: Sorry for the wait. But just change the path <img src="{$random}.png" alt="{$random}" /> to <img src="images/{$random}.png" alt="{$random}" />.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently written this which loads a different background on every pageload. Just replace the constant with the path to your images.

What it does is loop through your imagedirectory and randomly picks a file from it. This way you don't need to keep track of your images in an array or db or whatever. Just upload images to your imagedirectory and they will get picked (randomly).

Call like:

```
$oImg = new Backgrounds ;
echo $oImg -> successBg() ;


<?php

class Backgrounds
{

  public function __construct()
  {
  }

  public function succesBg()
  {  
    $aImages = $this->_imageArrays( \constants\IMAGESTRUE, "images/true/") ; 
    if(count($aImages)>1)
    {
      $iImage   = (int) array_rand( $aImages, 1 ) ;
      return $aImages[$iImage] ;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception("Image array " . $aImages . " is empty");
    }
  }


  private function _imageArrays( $sDir='', $sImgpath='' )
  {
    if ($handle = @opendir($sDir)) 
    {
      $aReturn = (array) array() ;
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
      {
        if(file_exists($sDir . $entry) && $entry!="." && $entry !="..")
        {
          $aReturn[] = $sImgpath . $entry ;
        }
      }
      return $aReturn ;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception("Could not open directory" . $sDir . "'" );
    }
  }

}

?>
```